# nginx: [emerg] "user" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/nginx.conf:1

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to install Oxidized on an Ubuntu 18.04 LTS server. I use Nginx as wab server and at a moment, it is said that I have to modify the file "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf", which I did by correctly following the documentation provided on the github page of the software. But, when I want to run the command `sudo nginx -t` the server raises this :

```
nginx: [emerg] "user" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/nginx.conf:1
```

So I've already tried to do `sudo chown -R /etc/nginx/sites-enabled` hoping that this might change anything. Here is my nginx.conf:

```
user oxidized oxidized;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        log_format main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local]    "$request"'
                    '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer"'
                    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main;

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

            ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/ja$

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
            include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

    server {
        listen      80;
        server_name oxidized.test.com www.oxidized.test.com;
        return      301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
        root        /usr/share/nginx/html;

        auth_basic "Restricted Access";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location / {
           proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8888/;
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }
    }
}
```

I don't that I did any mistakes but if anybody can help me to find where the problem is, it would be nice. 
Please answer me as soon as possible.

Comment: You said that doc says to modify file `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` but the error message is for file `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/nginx.conf`. Did you modify the right file ?

Comment: I did because I've created a symbolic link between the file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf and the directory /etc/nginx/sites-enabled by running `ln -s /etc/nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled`. That's why I don't understand where the problem is. But maybe it isn't enough. So I would like to know what I have forgotten.

Comment: You can't have file `nginx.conf` in both directories. the `user` directive should be in the main config file `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` and you should not have a `nginx.conf` file within `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`

Comment: The file `nginx.conf` isn't within `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` it is a symbolic link with `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file. Next, I don't know if that's the right to do because the doc that I followed is not really clear to me, I found. Here is the link to the doc as well as the tutorial: https://github.com/ytti/oxidized https://fakrul.me/2017/03/08/oxidized-network-device-configuration-backup/ .